# Antminer L3++ Where is Chain 1

Tags: mining-hardware, antminer

Is there supposed to be a Chain 1 here also?  My other miner has Chains 1 - 4.  If so, any troubleshooting steps or way to buy new part?  Thanks! :)
[image: antminer l3++ chain issue]

Comment: As there are 4 cards each with 2 power ports, I swapped known good power cables into what should be Chain#1.  I also swapped the serial cable with no effect.   I'm beginning to think it's the hardware which failed.  My friend purchased this and left it with me, so hopefully he did not receive a dud.